# Why does my algorithm become faster after having executed several times? (Java)

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, jvm, jit

I have a Sudoku solving algorithm for which my goal is to make as fast as possible. To test this algorithm, I run it multiple times and calculate the average. After noticing some weird numbers, I decided to print all times and got this result:

```
Execution Time : 4.257746 ms (#1)
Execution Time : 7.610686 ms (#2)
Execution Time : 6.277609 ms (#3)
Execution Time : 7.595707 ms (#4)
Execution Time : 7.610131 ms (#5)
Execution Time : 5.011104 ms (#6)
Execution Time : 3.970937 ms (#7)
Execution Time : 3.923783 ms (#8)
Execution Time : 4.070238 ms (#9)
Execution Time : 4.765347 ms (#10)
Execution Time : 0.818264 ms (#11)
Execution Time : 0.620216 ms (#12)
Execution Time : 0.679021 ms (#13)
Execution Time : 0.643516 ms (#14)
Execution Time : 0.718408 ms (#15)
Execution Time : 0.744481 ms (#16)
Execution Time : 0.760569 ms (#17)
Execution Time : 0.80384 ms (#18)
Execution Time : 0.75946 ms (#19)
Execution Time : 0.802176 ms (#20)
Execution Time : 66.032508 ms : average = 3.3016254000000003
```

After 10 to 15 executions (it varies randomly), the performance of the algorithm is drastically improves. If I run it several hundred times, it will eventually steady at around 0.3ms. Note that I run the algorithm once before this loop for JIT to do it's thing.

Furthermore, if I make the thread sleep for 2 seconds before running my loop, all my times are at 1ms (+/- 0.2).

Furthermore, if I solved a generic Sudoku (a grid with 1-9 diagonally) some 500 times before my loop, all my times are around 0.3ms (+/- 0.02).

Every solve is identical. All values are reset.

So my question is many-fold:

-Why does each solve time improve after consecutive solves?

-Why do I have a sudden drop in solve time after 10-15 solves?

Comment: JIT does not have to optimize on the first run. In fact, it most likely would not, since the cost of optimize the code cannot be well justified unless it is proved to be an important piece of code (run frequently enough).

Comment: You inadvertently created a sudoku-solving artificial lifeform which will probably evolve into Skynet. Quit now and start selling coconuts.

Comment: Small price to pay for hot time-travelling terminators from firefly.

Comment: Check JIT compilation using `-XX:+PrintCompilation` java option.

Comment: There is JVM launch option which can show JIT decisions about (de)optimization in real-time: http://blog.headius.com/2009/01/my-favorite-hotspot-jvm-flags.html

Comment: @Grzegorz link I've posted above tells about even more verbose option `-XX:+LogCompilation`

Comment: On this scale, it might be caused by how much `cpu` is used by other programs.

Comment: Note HotSpot uses a separate thread for compilation, so exactly when the compiled code gets swapped in may vary.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because [`JIT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) is compiling that method after `JVM` makes certain number of frequent calls to that method. In practice methods are not compiled the first time they are called. For each method JVM maintains a call count ,which is incremented every time the method is called. The JVM interprets a method until its call count exceeds a `JIT compilation threshold`. As the call count reaches threshold , `JIT` compiles and optimizes the `bytecodes` so that it run faster when next time it is called by `JVM`. Therefore, in your case the performance of the algorithm is drastically improving after every 10 to 15(at random) executions.

Comment: There can be something in the application itself that led to improvement. For example caching. At first runs some data might've been polled from external storage, but at consequent calls the same data might've been taken from the cache.

Comment: Yes, JIT does it on its own - relatively low level. But I am talking about pure business caching. For example - your application loads companies (they change very rare), so using cache may improve processing time dramatically. No JIT can do it for you.

Comment: @AlexKreutznaer I doubt it, since OP probably wrote the code him/herself. And it's a Sudoku solver, I don't see there being much use for caching.

Comment: @AlexKreutznaer: Yeah you are right.In general such caching by application itself increases the performance of the application.. because in that case JVM is saved from creating that object each time it is being required by the application..Although resource and and time consumed by modern JVMs to create an object is almost negligible now a days but still it does keeps matter for large objects.

Comment: @VishalK I developed many business applications. The problem is not object creation, the problem normally is time you spend acquiring external resources and getting data from them. That's where appropriate caching helps dramatically.

Comment: @AlexKreutznaer: Ok.Got your point. But I am talking in terms of `pools` of those objects whose creation consumes times as well as resources like `Connection Pools` , `Thread Pools` e.t.c.. Which for sure increases the performance of application by caching those ready made objects in a data structure and reuse them throughout the program.

Comment: @VishalK Yes, Connection Pools , Thread Pools e.t.c.. DO help. BUT it is still better to avoid loading object from database, and take the from cache.

Comment: @VishalK Even with a connection taken from pool, the process of retrieving object from a database comes at cost. Taking it from let say HashMap is WAY faster.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely - the JVM optimized its execution after several runs.

In addition to that the application itself could've done something that improved the execution results.

Without knowing in detail what you run it is difficult say something more precisely.

Do you use external resources - database connections, JMS queue/topics, etc..?
Do you use caching?

All that matters...

Comment: I added some more comments.

Comment: I only use pure and simple java. No queue, no cache, no threads, no db.
The application completely resets its data between each loop execution.

Comment: That's what I said - without knowing precisely what you did it is difficult to say. If you didn't use external resources and caching - then it was JIT that improved the execution results.